# State the domain and range of the following graphs.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

State the domain and range of the following graphs. Express each domain using interval notation and express each range using set-builder notation.
[image]

I think I'm beginning to understand using interval notation and set builder notation, but I'm still having trouble with the endpoints.

Comment: What is your question? You seem to have answered the question you put in the title. Also, the domain in the first graph should use square brackets; i.e. [-1,3] since it includes the endpoints.

Comment: Just making if i answered the question correctly, the domain and range for the circle gave me some confusion as well as the range of the second graph.

Answer (score 1):

ignoramus was right; your only mistake was not using square brackets in the domain of the first graph. The domain and range of a graph are nothing more than all the $x$- and $y$-values, respectively, that the graph includes, so everything else is correct.